# Why do I suddenly have this erroneous font in prompt and output of gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, fonts, gnome-terminal

I'm experiencing replacement of all occurrences of certain characters in the prompt and output of `gnome-terminal` (3.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04), e.g.

[image: prompt of gnome-terminal]

(latin `d` is replaced with some kind of uppercase D in exponent and some other pixels below).

`reset` and `clear` don't help. Copying the output/prompt returns the character sequence without replacements. What could cause this?

Comment: Have you checked your .bashrc file? More specifically the $PS1 theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen after reading from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` with `cat`. This seems to be fixed in version 3.20.2 of `gnome-terminal`. In older versions it's necessary to open a new terminal or try @Meow's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font --type string "Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline 11"
```

Comment: It's not that easy to reproduce, I assume `gnome-terminal` has been immunized.